# How to implement such a list as in the screenshot

Tags: swift

[image]

I want to make the settings screen the same as in the screenshot. Please tell me, is this implemented through a table view or through a collection view?

And how can I reduce the width of the cells and make them be in a frame like in the screenshot?

Comment: It seems somewhat suspicious you want to replicate a screenshot as an actual menu, almost like you want to fake that the menu you're creating is the source menu in the screenshot. Why are you doing this?

Comment: I want to implement a settings screen with cells not full screen width but like in the screenshot so that the cells are placed in a rounded rectangle.

Comment: UITableView with style insetGrouped.  See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/style)